# R -- Pivot Wider Over Multiple Names and Values

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I have data arranged in the following manner:

| Industry | Year | Country | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ind_A | 1999 | Country A | 1245 |
| Ind_A | 2000 | Country B | 132 |
| Ind_B | 2000 | Country A | 145 |
| Ind_C | 2000 | Country B | 122 |

I would like to re-arrange this data so that it looks like this:

| Country | Year | Industry A Value | Ind_B Value | Ind_C Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country A | 1999 | 1245 | NA | NA |
| Country A | 2000 | NA | 145 | NA |
| Country B | 2000 | NA | NA | 122 |

It seems like I should be able to use pivot_longer() function to achieve this but my attempts have not been able to produce what I am looking for.

I tried to use pivot_longer in a variety of ways. The code below is probably the closest I've gotten. It combines country and year combinations as individual values, which is what I would like to do with industry and value.

`df_wide <- df_long %>% pivot_wider(names_from = c(Country, Year), values_from = c(Value), values_fn = list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `names_from = "Industry` and you'll have it right

```
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Industry", values_from = "Value") %>% 
  arrange(Country)

# A tibble: 3 × 5
   Year Country  Ind_A Ind_B Ind_C
  <int> <chr>    <int> <int> <int>
1  1999 CountryA  1245    NA    NA
2  2000 CountryA    NA   145    NA
3  2000 CountryB   132    NA   122
```